# Trouble reading data and store in a object type instance variable

Tags: java

I have created a following instance variable in Student Class:

```
private String name;
private char gender;     // 'M' / 'F'
private Date birthday;
private Preference pref;
private boolean matched;
```

for Preference class I created

`private int quietTime; // scale of 1-10
 private int music;     // 1 - 10
 private int reading;   // 1 - 10
 private int chatting;  // 1 - 10`

for Date class I created

`private int year;  // between 1900 to 3000
 private int month; // between 1 to 12, 1 is jan;
 private int day;   // between 1- 31 assume feb max is 28 days!`

The trouble is my main method I try to import the following libraries

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
```

and I want to read the txt file and store data on each one to the Student instance variables, below is my code I tried but I received the error about 
" student cannot be resolved to a variable "
and for example below is one of the line from the text file:

`Abhay  F   1-5-1994    0   0   0   0 // seperate by tab and '-'`

My code for match class - the main method class:

```
`
  Student[] students = new Student[100];
  int bestScore = 0;
  String readInfo = "";

  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("Students.txt")).useDelimiter("\t-");

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      readInfo = inFile.next();
      student[i] = readInfo;
  }
  inFile.close();
 }
}

while(1) {
  r.nextBoolean();
  if (!nextBoolean())
  {
    return true;
  }

`
```

I just start to learn java for ten days, I am completely a newbie, May someone help me with how to fix the error, i am really appercate it!!

Comment: Well, do you have a variable called `student`?

Comment: You need to convert the String into a Student object. Java doesn't do that for you.

Comment: I suggest that you break the problem down into small pieces. It appears that you are trying to read in a list of 100 students before you have even figured out how to read in ONE. Start there. Write a small method that reads each piece of data that represents a single student.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to all of your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read or write something to file, you can use these streams. It is better than Scanner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("path\\to\\your\\file.txt")));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("path\\to\\your\\second\\file.txt")));
    //read one line from your file
    String line = reader.readLine();
    //write something to your file
    writer.write(line);
}
```

If you want to write the whole object into file, Java has ObjectInput/Output streams.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("yourFile.bin"))); //or any file type
    ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("yourFile.bin")));

    output.writeObject(yourObject);
    YourObject yourObject = input.readObject();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting here specifically is related to the fact that you instantiated an array of name "students" but you then reference an array of name "student".

Since you never instantiated a student array, you get the following error : student cannot be resolved to a variable.

Try:

```
students[i] = readInfo;
```